# Unpermitted Parameters Accepts Nested Attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I have been banging my head on a wall for a good six hours. I have gotten this to work before and seemingly have everything exactly the same. I am getting an **Unpermitted parameters: test** error. This is my layout:

User.rb

```
has_many :tests
accepts_nested_attributes_for :tests, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
```

Test.rb

```
belongs_to :user
```

Users Controller

```
def update
  current_user.update_attributes(user_params)
  redirect_to root_path
end

def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :tests_attributes => [:id, :response])
end
```

Tests Contoller

```
def show
  @test = Test.where(:secure_id => params[:id]).first
  @user = User.find(@test.user_id)
end

def test_params
  params.require(:test).permit(:user_id, :test_name, :secure_id)
end
```

test/show.html.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for @user, :url => admin_user_path(@user) do |u| %>
  <%= u.simple_fields_for @test do |as| %>
    <%= as.label :response %><br>
    <%= as.text_area :response, :class => "tinymce", :rows => 15 %><br>
  <% end %>

  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <%= u.input :field_name,  :label => false, :boolean_style => :inline %>
      </td>
      <td>Field Name</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <br /><br />

  <%= u.submit 'Update User', :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
  <br /><br />
<% end %>
```

I changed names and omitted code due to company policy. If anymore code is needed please let me know and I will provide it.

I have went through tons of stackoverflow posts, read simple_forms nested attributes section, and many other things.

Comment: Check the [docs](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/wiki/Nested-Models), notice how they are passing in `:parts` instead of `@parts` when using the `simple_fields_for` method (replace "parts" with "test" in your case). I only use Rails as an API sever, so I can't say if that will fix your problem ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First parameter for `fields_for` must be a record name, that is `:tests` in your case (User has_many :**tests**). And the second parameter is a record object, that will be used to render the inputs inside `fields_for`. You pass `@test` as first parameter and `fields_for` treats this as record name and adds `test` parameter which is not allowed in your strong params.

So, it should look like this:

```
<%= u.simple_fields_for :tests, @test do |as| %>
```

Comment: So doing this gets rid of the error and it actually processes, so thank you very much! I am now running into an issue with my checkbox value not actually saving to the database. I get no errors, but the user parameter is not being processed in the console:

`Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"Ar04oEJ3inm+/hnG8OPYIYnBYFbb4xZYzmFDyriOnSk=", "user"=>{"tests_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"response"=>"<p>&nbsp;asdfasdfasfasdfasdfadf</p>", "id"=>"35"}}}, "commit"=>"Update User", "id"=>"1"}
`

The user should have the checkbox field name in there too. Strange.

Comment: @Matthew Did you change anything else? It seems that inputs related to user generated not correctly, they don't have `user` in their names. You can see in parameters you posted that `"id"=>"1"` is outside `user` hash. Maybe you changed arguments for `simple_form_for`?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The issue is actually something else entirely and I believe the form is now working. We have another page to adjust accesses and that form doesn't work on development either, it is strange, but something I can bring up with my superior.

Thanks for the help and I have chosen your answer as the correct one!