# form_for nested attributes: create doesn't save to DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a User Model and a Profile model. User

```
has_one :profile, dependent: :destroy
after_create :create_profile
has_many :reviews, dependent: :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile
```

So, after sign_up User gets redirected to a new_user_profile_path to create a Profile

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
    protected
      def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
        new_user_profile_path(current_user.id)
      end
end
```

Profile#new has a form_for nested attributes and looks the following

```
<%= form_for(@user, url: user_profile_path(@user), method: :post) do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :profile, @profile do |profile_fields| %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= profile_fields.label :about %>
      <%= profile_fields.text_area :about %>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
      <%= profile_fields.file_field :avatar %>
      <% profile_fields.label "Profile photo" %>
    </div>

  <% end %>


    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :street %>
        <%= f.text_area :street %>
    </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>

<% end %>
```

The issue is, this form doesn't save neither to user nor to profile. Parameters are being passed as follows

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"some_token", "user"=>{"profile_attributes"=>{"about"=>"mpl", "avatar"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00007fb710cc4a88 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/0q/y8_xn1q57wn1_x9zhph1fpz00000gn/T/RackMultipart20191127-9283-sjkiqb.jpg>, @original_filename="055g.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"user[profile_attributes][avatar]\"; filename=\"055g.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">}, "street"=>"nmp"}, "commit"=>"Update User", "user_id"=>"14"}
```

The form has a submit button, which by defauls states "Update user", so I thought maybe I need an update method in User, to make it work. But it didn't help. Here is my UsersController

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    @user.save
  end

  def update
    current_user.update_attributes(user_params)
    redirect_to user_profile_path(@user)
  end

  private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :first_name, :last_name, :street, :house_number, :city, :zip_code, profile_attributes: [:about, :avatar])
  end

end
```

And my ProfilesController:

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_profile, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def show
    @user = User.eager_load(:profile).find(params[:user_id])
    @profile = @user.profile
    @review = Review.new
    @reviews = Review.where(profile: @profile) 
  end

  def new
    @user = current_user
    @profile = Profile.new
  end

  def edit
    @profile = @user.profile
  end

  def create
    @user = current_user
    @profile = @user.build_profile(profile_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @profile.save
        format.html { redirect_to user_profile_path(current_user.id), notice: 'Profile was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @profile }
      else
        format.html { render :new, notice: 'Did not save' }
        format.json { render json: @profile.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @profile.update(profile_params)
        format.html { redirect_to user_profile_path(current_user.id), notice: 'Profile was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @profile }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @profile.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @profile.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to users_url, notice: 'Profile was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private

    def set_profile
      @profile = current_user.profile
    end

    def profile_params
      params.permit(:about, :avatar)
    end

end
```

I looked everywehre, also here for the form [Unpermitted Parameters Accepts Nested Attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34279710/unpermitted-parameters-accepts-nested-attributes) , but nothing I do makes it save to DB. Also, I tried

```
params.require(:profile).permit(:about, :avatar)
```

But it returned a very weird error:

```
ActiveSupport::MessageVerifier::InvalidSignature @profile = Profile.new(profile_params)
```

What am I doing wrong? I am new to Rails and I am really stuck.

P.S. Here is my UserModel

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable,
         :omniauthable, omniauth_providers: %i[facebook]


    has_one :profile, dependent: :destroy
    after_create :create_profile
    has_many :reviews, dependent: :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile
    validates :first_name, presence: true
    validates :last_name, presence: true

    def self.from_omniauth(auth)
        where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
            user.email = auth.info.email
            user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0, 20]
            name = auth.info.name
            user.first_name = name.split(" ")[0]
            user.last_name = name.split(" ")[1] 
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Please add your User class to the question.

Comment: Which rails version are you using? Your `form_for` declaration could just be `form_for @user do` --> why do you not use that?

Comment: I tried, but it didn't work. I am absolutely sure, that this is not an ussue in my case

Comment: The `user_profile_path` will point to the `ProfileController`, yet your form is creating a `:user` to save. Could you show us the logfile (`development.log`) where we can see 1) which controller is actually hit on save, and 2) what data is sent (and which will be blocked by the strong parameters).

Comment: Well, I really want to save to Profile. So, basically, when saved, there will be shown user attributes, like street on the profile page together with the profile attributes, like about. The user is being created upong sign_up, this form only updates the created user. And yes, the form refers to the Profile Controller, but my create action in the Profiles Controller won't save. I know, I can add address to the Profile, not to ser and this could solve the problem. But I am desperate to find a solutuin for what I have now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, this seems like a good answer to my question, but not the solution, so maybe someone would like to comment on this. For me it's something very new and interesting. The main challenge seems to be validating partial objects. As upon sign_up I just submit Name, email, and password and in the next step I ask for strett, I split a single model across two forms. This splitting of models across forms means you have to ask awkward questions like, "Hey, ActiveRecord, is the half of this object I have so far valid?" I don't think ActiveRecord was designed for validating parts of objects.

Apparently there is a gem called Wicked, which deals with Building Partial Objects Step by Step - looks like it's way too pro level for me. But if someone is willing to support me in trying this out, that'll be great. There is also a good article on this topic, where I quitet from https://www.honeybadger.io/blog/multi-step-forms-in-rails/

Comment: ActiveRecord validations support the `:on` option and the `save` and `valid?` methods support a `:context` option, using that is pretty easy to set up partial validations depending on the context. Actually, check the example on the guide https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#on